# Finding Values For Cd and Ccm

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, photodiode

[image]

When choosing an op amp for your system based on the system's required bandwidth, the value for Cin must be calculated for the required gain-bandwidth product. I understand that Cj is the junction capacitance of the photodiode, but how can we choose the values for Cd and Ccm if we do not have a chosen op amp yet?

What values must I use to find the sum of Cin?

Comment: Are we done here Kevin?

Answer (score 0):

A rule you can follow is try and aim for the added capacitance from your op-amp being **no more** than about 30% of the photodiode capacitance. When you pick your op-amp this is what you should aim for. Clearly, this may not always work out (especially if you have a particularly fast photodiode) because there may be about a picofarad just from your PCB tracks.

That's how I'd approach it anyway.